# Search a Field in a MySQL Database for Multiple Versions of a String Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I need to search a field in a table in a MySQL database for multiple versions of a string. For example, a user might search for a name of a store with the name "Strings & Things" but might search for it using "Strings and Things." Also, the query also searches a description field that might have the name stored as "Strings & Things." The dirty solution is to test for the existence of " & " or " and " in the search and then add additional OR statements to the sql statement but regardless, any existence of " & " or " and " in the query would require three (or rather, since I'm searching in two fields, six) lookups for "Strings and Things," "Strings & Things" and "Strings & Things." Is there a simple way of combining this into one search term or, if possible, to do some of the heavier lifting on the sql side of things. For the record, I'm using PHP. Full code isn't necessary. Pseudo code or a resource explaining this topic would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html)

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (column1,column2) 
     AGAINST ('+value1 +value2 +value3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I can't believe I wasn't aware of this before. Thanks.